# How to create Masstransit's Test Harness with Automock?

Tags: unit-testing, moq, masstransit, automocking

In order to create the test harness for the `SubmitOrderConsumer`, I will have to build a `ServiceCollection` containing all the depdencies of `SubmitOrderConsumer`.

```
Mock<INotifier> mockNotifier = new Mock<INotifier>();
Mock<IStockChecker> mockStockChecker = new Mock<IStockChecker>();
Mock<IFidelityUpdater> mockFidelityUpdater = new Mock<IFidelityUpdater>();
Mock<IPromotionManager> mockPromotionManager = new Mock<IPromotionManager>();
await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();
    })
    .AddSingleton<INotifier>(mockNotifier.Object)
    .AddSingleton<IStockChecker>(mockStockChecker.Object)
    .AddSingleton<IFidelityUpdater>(mockFidelityUpdater.Object)
    .AddSingleton<IPromotionManager>(mockPromotionManager.Object)
    ..
    .BuildServiceProvider(true);ds

var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();
...
mockNotifier.Verify(...)
```

The `Moq.Automock` library helps me to create the `SubmitOrderConsumer` and auto-mock all its depdencies so the above codes is reduced to

```
AutoMocker mocker = new AutoMocker();
await using var provider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();
    })
    .AddSingleton(mocker.CreateInstance<SubmitOrderConsumer>())
    .BuildServiceProvider(true);

var harness = provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();
...
mocker.GetMock<INotifier>().Verify(...)
```

Question:

The class `AutoMocker` is also a `IServiceProvider`, so the above codes have 2 `IServiceProvider`:

- the first `IServiceProvider` is the `mocker` which can resolve the `SubmitOrderConsumer`
- the second `IServiceProvider` is the `provider` which can resolve the `ITestHarness`

is it possible to create the `ITestHarness` with my mocker `IServiceProvider`? something like

```
ITestHarness harness = new ContainerTestHarness(mocker);
```

Comment: Never used auto mocker, not a clue. Good luck.

Comment: I didn't find out if it is possible to create the test harness "manually" (without the help of a ServiceCollection). For now, I will just use 2 ServiceProvider, just hiding one in the "StartTestHarnessFor" function

https://gist.github.com/duongphuhiep/15f223437bfd88a05de09c420473133b